# I need help to Copy and Paste certain cells in a row to another sheet if criteria is met

Tags: google-apps-script

I only wanted to copy column A, B,C, and G and on my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aJ841TlpYrBhupotKO4-TQdDNHb1DwKPsR-HZ2bwXkg/edit?usp=sharing). I wanted it to be transferred to sheet 1 then delete the row from sheet2.

So basically what I wanted is this to happen and after that delete the row on sheet2.

```
"column A" ---> "column A"  
"column B" ---> "column B"  
"column C" ---> "column D"  
"column G" ---> "column C"
```

My current script copies the whole row and I'm not sure how to make it work as I have mentioned above. I can't use query function, since sheet 1 is automatically being populated.

```
function onEdit(event) {
 // assumes source data in sheet named main
 // target sheet of move to named Completed
 // getColumn with drop-downs is currently set to column 3 or C
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

 if(s.getName() == "Sheet2" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "Done") {
   var row = r.getRow();
   var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("URL Checklist Raw");
   var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
   s.deleteRow(row);
 } 
}
```

Comment: In your question you describe that column `C` should go into column `D`. However, after checking out the example Sheet you linked seems that this is not always the case. If `C` is larger or equal than `C`, it looks like that value should be placed into `E` instead of `D`. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make the sample sheet much clearer, the headers are for example purpose only.

But I still want the column C to go column D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily by using the [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) method of the [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) class. The idea is that the values of the range are fetched, re-ordered, and then set to the destination values. You can see below a modified version of the original code that accomplishes what you describe.

Additionally, instead of getting the `target` range and setting the values to it, you can simply use the [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method, which allows for more concise code:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
 // assumes source data in sheet named main
 // target sheet of move to named Completed
 // getColumn with drop-downs is currently set to column 3 or C
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

 if(s.getName() == "Sheet2" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "Done") {
   var row = r.getRow();
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var values = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).getValues()[0];
   var resultRow = [values[0], values[1], values[6], values[2]];
   targetSheet.appendRow(resultRow);
   s.deleteRow(row);
 } 
}
```

Comment: @NiñoRegala Apologies, there was a bug. Please re-try with above code. Bear in mind that the Sheet name specified is "Sheet1" (which should work in your shared test Sheet as tested) despite the Sheet name in your original code snippet was "URL Checklist Raw"

Comment: Thank you. It's working now.

Yeah, kinda missed that one when I did the test sheet. :)

Comment: @NiñoRegala No worries! :) Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in case my answer was useful to you. Have a good day!

Comment: Thanks this really helped me a lot. I don't have any experience on coding. :)

Don't want to stretch you being helpful to me.

But, I tried to edit and reuse the code for another purpose but I wanted it to be dynamic and not just watching 1 sheet, can that be possible?

Comment: Hello @NiñoRegala, glad to know! If you wanted to watch let's say `Sheet2` **and** `Sheet3`, you simply would need to change `if(s.getName() == "Sheet2" && ...` for `if((s.getName() == "Sheet2" || s.getName() == "Sheet3") && ...`. Of course, if you decide to do this, you'll have to make sure that the setup of both of them is the same (in terms of rows, columns and headers). If you have more questions, please consider creating a brand new question or contacting me through the Form in my profile. Cheers!